# Changing the format of a date in a column of a comma delimited file .csv in unix

Tags: csv, awk, sed

I need a unix command that would convert the following .csv table using("," rather than ,) from:

[image]
..
to

[image]

I think an awk or sed command will be able to do it but I can't figure it out.

For those who want to see the raw csv:

```
"Area","Locale","Date","Prefix","INT","Cap","CF","loss","Fall","WR"
"base","NewYork","20150331","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20150930","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20160331","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20160930","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20170331","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20170929","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20180329","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20180928","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","20190329","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
```

to

```
"Area","Locale","Date","Prefix","INT","Cap","CF","loss","Fall","WR"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/29/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/28/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
```

Comment: Perl has a module called `Text::CSV` that's quite good at parsing CSV. Is perl an option?

Comment: This is not showing the contents of the file. Is it really comma-separated? It matters.

Comment: Another vote for using Perl or Python or something with an actual CSV parser rather than trying to do this with a shell script...

Comment: Some suggestions: 1) show us a sample of your input data and the desired output _in text format_, rather than screenshots and 2) show us what you've tried already

Comment: request is not clear (request for a date conversion in title and quoted value/separator in request, sample is not text CSV but graphical interpretation of a csv [excel like]). Need more information and precision

Comment: @NeronLeVelu clearly.... I will edit the question

Comment: @Sobrique unfortunately not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Through Perl.

```
$ perl -pe 's~^([^,]*,[^,]*,")(\d{4})(0([1-9])|(1[012]))(\d{2})"~\1\4\5/\6/\2"~' file
"Area","Locale","Date","Prefix","INT","Cap","CF","loss","Fall","WR"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/29/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/28/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","12/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
```

Through sed,

I just replaced `\d` in the above Perl regex to `[0-9]` because sed won't support `\d` notation.

```
$ sed -r 's~^([^,]*,[^,]*,")([0-9]{4})(0([1-9])|(1[012]))([0-9]{2})"~\1\4\5/\6/\2"~' file
"Area","Locale","Date","Prefix","INT","Cap","CF","loss","Fall","WR"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/29/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/28/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","12/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
```

Comment: I suspect the OP would want leading zeros stripped from day numbers since that's apparently what he wants for month numbers. Try it with a date of `20150305` as I think the desired output would be `3/5/2015` rather than `3/05/2015`.

Comment: i think he wants to remove the 0 only in month part.

Comment: yup we can't tell for sure without the OP providing sample input/output showing that case so we're guessing. In my experience people remove or leave all leading 0s not just some, e.g. `3/5/2015` or `03/05/2015` rather than mixed `3/05/2015` or `03/5/2015`, but YMMV.

Comment: if he wish, i will edit my answer. It's just a minor edit to the original regex :)

Answer (score 2):

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="\",\""}
       {$3 = substr($3,5,2)+0 "/" substr($3,7,2)+0 "/" substr($3,1,4)} 1' file
"Area","Locale","0/0/Date","Prefix","INT","Cap","CF","loss","Fall","WR"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/30/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/31/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/29/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","9/28/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","3/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
```

The `+0`s are to convert `03` to `3` etc. per your expected output.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your file is called `raw`:

```
cat <(head -n 1 raw) <(while read Area Locale Date Prefix INT Cap CF loss Fall WR; do echo \"${Area}\",\"${Locale}\",\"${Date:4:2}/${Date:6:2}/${Date:0:4}\",\"${Prefix}\",\"${INT}\",\"${Cap}\",\"${CF}\",\"${loss}\",\"${Fall}\",\"${WR}\"; done < <(tail -n +2 raw | column -ts"," | tr -d \"))
```

Walkthrough: splits the file using `column` and strips '"' using `tr`. Then reads all columns into parameters only formatting `Date`. Later it activates the while on the entire file leaving out the headr (using `tail`) and prepends the header using `head` to a temporary descriptor opened using `<()` and `cat`.

Output:

```
"Area","Locale","Date","Prefix","INT","Cap","CF","loss","Fall","WR"
"base","NewYork","03/31/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","09/30/2015","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","03/31/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","09/30/2016","100","0","3.225","3.225","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","03/31/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","09/29/2017","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","03/29/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","09/28/2018","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
"base","NewYork","03/29/2019","100","0","3.475","3.475","0","0","0"
```

Note that this can be used to manipulate other data, since everything is parsed... But, for parsing `csv` files, you should use a `csv` parser :)